# Extract specific attribute from flat file item writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an object returned from item processor.

```
  public class PcdRateMapper
{
    private Pcdrate pcdRate;
    private Boolean isValidPcdRate;

    public PcdRateMapper ()
    {
        // pcdRate = new Pcdrate ();
    }

    public Pcdrate getPcdRate ()
    {
        return pcdRate;
    }

    public void setPcdRate (Pcdrate pcdRate)
    {
        this.pcdRate = pcdRate;
    }

    public Boolean getIsValidPcdRate ()
    {
        return isValidPcdRate;
    }

    public void setIsValidPcdRate (Boolean isValidPcdRate)
    {
        this.isValidPcdRate = isValidPcdRate;
    }
```

Now i want to extract only Pcdrate object values in my item writer. How can I do this. Currently I'm using following spring configuration but getting invalid property exception. Thanks in advance.

```
<

property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                <property name=""></property>
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean


    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                            <property name=""></property>
                            <property name="names"
                                value="company, subcoy" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

The invalid property exception may stem from

```
 <property name=""></property>
```

where the property name is an empty string. You have that twice in the code above, remove it.

Your xml structure seems to be invalid, see [spring_bean_definition](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm)
to see how it should look like.

On the bean of type BeanWrapperFieldExtractor you must set the property 'names' to the names of properties that you want to extraxt, in your case 'pcdRate'.

It should be configured like this :

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
    <property name="names" value="pcdRate" />
 </bean>
```